# Unable to compile programs in Ubuntu with Geany

Tags: programming, c++, compiler

[image: Compilation error in Geany] I'm having trouble compiling a simple C++ program in Geany. The result is same even if i just use terminal(not using Geany).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install build-essential package?

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

It contains gcc and g++ compilers for C and C++ languages respectively.

Comment: Nope, just found out that, g++ isn't installed by default. I thought it comes by default with linux.

Comment: @KanthalaRaghu, you can accept **and** upvote an answer. If you aren't doing one or the other, it would be helpful to the person who took the effort to answer to know in what way the answer was deficient.